# Is there any autoencoder trained on ImageNet?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder

I want to build an auto-encoder for image.

ResNet101 trained on ImageNet is employed as my encoder.
(Softmax layer will be removed.)

Then, I build a decoder for it, and try to train it.

But I found it take extremely long time...

Is there any autoencoder trained on ImageNet?
It does not have to be ResNet.